# Erasing/Replacing an empty substring

Tags: java, regex, string

I am currently working on something, that should count the words, given from a file of Tweets. I am replacing special characters and words which are just two characters short with whitespace. Because of that, later I can get double Whitespaces, which i am replacing in the next line. The variable "words" is a HashMap in which the corresponding frequenzy of the word is stored.

```
tweet = tweet.replaceAll("[^\\d\\p{L} ]", " ");
tweet = tweet.replaceAll("\\b.{1,2}\\b", " ");
tweet = tweet.replaceAll("\\s{2,}",  " ");
tweet = tweet.toLowerCase();
for (String word : tweet.split(" ")){
if (words.containsKey(word)){
        words.put(word, words.get(word)+1);
} else {
        words.put(word, 1);
```

My Problem is, that the generated list of words with their frequenzy, contains the empty string. Most of the times this is the string wich is the most often found. I don't get where this comes from and how I can get rid of it and hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are replacing the matched "words" with spaces, you are going to end up with sequences of multiple spaces at the beginning and end of the `tweet` string ... and in the middle.  But you are splitting it using a single space as the separator.  The empty strings represent the stuff between successive spaces.

One possible fix:

```
tweet = tweet.trim();
for (String word : tweet.split("\\s+")) {
```

(The regex `\s+` means "one or more white-space character.)

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
tweet.trim().split(" +")
```

Also consider combining diacritical marks as belonging to words `\pM`.

```
tweet = tweet.replaceAll("[^\\d\\p{L}\\p{M}]", " ");
```

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the empty string appears when a tweet begins or ends with a space.

```
tweet = tweet.trim(); // remove leading and trailing space
```